# Can I dedupe by primary email or primary phone only?

Tags: contacts, duplicate-contacts, dedupe-rules

I want to dedupe contacts who have the same primary email address (ditto for contacts with the same primary phone). However, I'm not seeing a way to include primary-ness as a factor in a dedupe rule. Am I missing something there, or does anyone know of any workarounds?

The context is that we are integrating with two different tools, one of which considers email to be a unique identifier (so it will automatically merge two contacts with the same email, regardless of name or other info) and the other considers phone to be a unique identifier. We only integrate primary phone and primary email with these two systems. Since, of course, people can and do share emails and phones and have multiple emails and phones, and that is reflected in our Civi data, we're figuring the best we can do is try to keep primary email and primary phone as unique ids. But when I try to find duplicates with my existing de-dupe rules, it finds many matches where maybe one of the contacts has that value as primary but the other has that value not primary; I don't need to de-dupe those. Any ideas?